# Send SMS individually with Intents in Android

Tags: android, sms

How can I send individual SMS to multiple recipients using an `Intent` only? (no SMSManager!) Is this even possible? I have tried the following solution but it creates a group message (MMS):

```
private void sendSMS(String[] phoneNumbers, String message){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s :
            phoneNumbers) {
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append(";");
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + sb.toString()));  // This ensures only SMS apps respond
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Again, the goal is to send a text to each recipient individually, not as a group message. I cannot use `SMSManager` because as of 2019 the Google Play Store prohibits sending SMS unless your app is the default messaging app (with some exceptions).

Comment: "How can I send individual SMS to multiple recipients using an Intent only?" -- that will depend entirely on the user's SMS client. There are hundreds of these. How they handle your unusual `Intent` (`ACTION_VIEW` to send???) is up to the developers of those SMS clients.

Comment: @CommonsWare In regards to me using ACTION_VIEW, I changed that back to ACTION_SEND. Sorry, wasn't meant to confuse, that was a remnant of some code I tried in a separate answer. However, your answer to the question is that sending individual SMS versus group MMS is out of my control?

Comment: "However, your answer to the question is that sending individual SMS versus group MMS is out of my control? " -- if you are using an `Intent`, then yes.